# Best way for creating reports in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, report

After building my application in ASP.NET MVC and MS sql server, I would now like to display some statistics regarding my data.

What would be the easiest way to create HTML reports which are built of data crossing several tables? (Once the fields are picked they'll be static, meanning a single view is required)

I though their ought to be something in the lines of a wizard letting you drag fields from your tables to a form and generates the logic behind...

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [blog post about this in September](http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/1462680178/simple-report-generation-in-asp-net-mvc). It's a way to render a PDF content type using an RPT file in the application. It covers everything except the creation of the RDLC file, including how to write unit tests for the controller.

Comment: Thanks man! It really helped me to use my old reports in the new web app!

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/reporting-services.aspx)?

Comment: It seems that this is the tool that I was looking for, however it is not included in the Express edition (2008). Am I correct?

Is there anything like that freeware?

Comment: Check this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166.aspx There is a subset of SSRS available in SQL Express.

Answer (score 0):

"I though their ought to be something in the lines of a wizard letting you drag fields from your tables to a form and generates the logic behind..." - this is the basic idea behind ASP.NET WebForms.  But, please do not abandon MVC in favour of WebForms.

One way to achieve what you want is to create a class representing your stats, e.g.

```
public class Statistic
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
}
```

Your Model code could populate an `IList<Statistic>` instance which is passed to your View, which renders the stats accordingly.

Comment: But then will the view rendering could be automaticly generated from class Statistic?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Dynamic Data .... http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata